# Two classes which are very similar, I want to pass one or the other into a method

Tags: c#, interface

I have two classes, consider the following:

```
public class Class1
{
   public int CustomerID;
   public int DriverID;
   public int EmployeeID;
}

public class Class2
{
   public int CustomerID;
   public int DriverID;
   public int EmployeeID;      
}
```

I want to then write a method which does something with either one of these methods, but my program won't know which one until runtime.

```
public void DoSomething(???)
{
  if (???.GetType() == typeof(Class1)
  {
    //do stuff related to class 1
  }

  if (???.GetType() == typeof(Class2)
  {
    //do stuff related to class 2
  }
}
```

How am I able to pass one of those classes into that method, considering they are different types? I then need to check the type to perform separate actions.

The way this will be used in my application is that Class1 and Class2 will be linked to a ParentClass, and on that ParentClass it will dictate which linked object should be used (either Class1 and Class2) e.g. ParentClass will have a bool on it, and if bool is true, then use Class1 else use Class2, and depending on that boolean is what I want to pass into that method. I don't want to create a separate method as I think it will be best to do this.

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: You could define an interface containing the common method and properties and change the two classes so that both implement it. Then define your method to take a parameter of this interface type

Comment: You've tagged this post with "interface", but you're not using one. An interface would solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a base class with the properties in common.

The classes derive from it with an implementation of the method `DoSomeThing`.
Then, your method `DoSomeThing` is called autotomatically for the right type,

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
   public int CustomerID;
   public int DriverID;
   public int EmployeeID;  
   public abstract void DoSomeThing();    
}

public abstract Class1
{
   public override void DoSomeThing(){}
}

public abstract Class
{
   public override void DoSomeThing(){}
}

public void DoSomething(BaseClass class)
{
    class.DoSomeThing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my preference is to do interfaces over inheritance if I can. Allows to be a little more flexible I think in the future.

```
public static void DoSomething(IDoSomething MyObject)
{
    MyObject.DoSomeMethod();
 }
 interface IDoSomething
 {
    void DoSomeMethod();
 }
 public class Class1 : IDoSomething
 {
    public int CustomerID;
    public int DriverID;
    public int EmployeeID;

     public void DoSomeMethod()
     {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
 }

 public class Class2 : IDoSomething
 {
    public int CustomerID;
    public int DriverID;
    public int EmployeeID;

    public void DoSomeMethod()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

you could try somehing like this:

```
    public static  void DoSomething(object MyObject)
    {
        if (MyObject.GetType() == typeof(Class1))
        {
            //   (MyObject as Class1 )
        }

        if (MyObject.GetType() == typeof(Class2))
        {
            //   (MyObject as Class2 )
        }
    }
```